# jsPDF addImage() PNG images not shown

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to render some images, there are some GIF, PNG, JPEG images, and I just use the image src link.

All other image are fine and can be loaded and displayed well, but some images just displayed blank, and I observed they are PNG file. Although they are blank, the file size can tell the image is already embeded.

I inspected inside the addImage function and see all images (including those PNG img) binary are loaded correctly on this line before write to file: https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/blob/master/src/modules/addimage.js#L855

[image]

so that is not an image loading problem, it is the jsPDF not render correctly.

This is the code I used to add image:

```
doc.addImage({
    imageData: srcLink,
    format: "JPEG",
    x: x,
    y: y,
    width: w,
    height: h,
    compression: "SLOW",
});
```

If I change format to `PNG` (for all image), jsPDF failed with error say invalid PNG format for some images.

So I wrote function to parse image format and use correct format for all different image, but also have the same error invalid PNG format for some images.

So I guess `JPEG` is good for all.

Don't know why???